# Copy and rename XLSX file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename, xlsx

I have many XLSX files that I will need to copy to a new location and rename. The Excel files appear to be copied to the new location, but when I open them, I keep getting the "found unreadable content" error message, and all the data is gone.

I use an asterisk to find the file, and then I want to rename it so that it doesn't have the date string.

This is the code I'm using:

```
set OrigLocn=C:\OldLocation\

set NewLocn=C:\NewLocation\

copy "%OrigLocn%S5820-003-terms-sg*" "%NewLocn%S5820-003-terms-sg.xlsx"
copy "%OrigLocn%S5921-293-terms-addp*" "%NewLocn%S5921-293-terms-addp.xlsx"
copy "%OrigLocn%S5921-293-terms-sg*" "%NewLocn%S5921-293-terms-sg.xlsx"
copy "%OrigLocn%S5921-349-terms-addp*" "%NewLocn%S5921-349-terms-addp.xlsx"
```

Comment: If you replace `copy` with `echo` you can see what it's trying to do. Maybe that'll help?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the xcopy command to copy over multiple files then use REN to change the name.

XCOPY: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

REN: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

change `copy` to `copy /b`. This copies in binary mode but the default is ascii mode which terminates the copy when certain binary sequences are encountered.

Comment: This used to be the case - Windows now copies in binary mode by default.  `/b is the default value for copy, unless copy combines files.` from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using the wildcard in the copy command will cause the target file to be concatenated if more than one file matches the filespec.

if this is the case then you'll need different code to remove the date string.